# Triangle next to the text

Tags: html, css, angularjs, css-shapes, smart-table

I want to add small triangle next to the text in small table. How can I do it? Here is my code:

```
<tr>
     <th st-sort="firstname" class>Firstname</th>
     <th st-sort="lastname" class>Lastname</th>
     <th st-sort="street" class>Street</th>
     <th st-sort="town" class>Town</th>
     <th st-sort="zipCode" class>ZipCode</th>  
</tr>
```

Thank you very much for answers.

Comment: What do you mean by 'triangle'? A small caret?

Comment: When you click on the table header the icon do appear. Check [this](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/#examples-section)

Comment: create a span tag next to the text and with the help of pseudo class style it accordingly.

Comment: try [this](http://codepen.io/drops/pen/jEQZgb), edit to tweak position

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick demo of how this can be achieved using a `pseudo element`:

```css
div{
  position:relative;
  padding-left:30px;
  height:30px;
  font-size:30px;
  line-height:30px;
  display:inline-block;
  }
div:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  border-left:15px solid red;
  border-top: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  }
```

```html
<div>Hello World</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the "Font awesome CSS framework" for such icons. It is very simple to implement in the project and also it is open source.

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/caret-up/

Comment: thaks, but i do it with .st-sort-ascent:before {
 content: "\25B4";
}

.st-sort-descent:before {
 content: "\25BE";
}

Answer (score 0):

You can add a triangle using css, see example [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/)

Alternatively you may also use [fontawesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) or a similar font with triangles included.

**Note** : there is no javascript required in both cases.

Comment: thaks, but i do it with .st-sort-ascent:before {
 content: "\25B4";
}

.st-sort-descent:before {
 content: "\25BE";
}

Answer (score 0):

Here - try this in CSS.  You can adjust the border widths to change the shape and size of the arrow, and you can either use a transform or switch which sides have borders if you want the arrow to point another direction.  Just position the arrow div where you want it next to the text.

```css
.triangleDiv {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px 0 10px 10px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #007bff;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangleDiv"></div>
```

Comment: thaks, but i do it with .st-sort-ascent:before {
 content: "\25B4";
}

.st-sort-descent:before {
 content: "\25BE";
}

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a small amount of text you need to do, you can do it manually by adding a unicode triangle to the existing text:

```
<tr>
 <th st-sort="firstname" class>&#9650;Firstname</th>
 <th st-sort="lastname" class&#9650;>Lastname</th>
 <th st-sort="street" class>&#9650;Street</th>
 <th st-sort="town" class>&#9650;Town</th>
 <th st-sort="zipCode" class>&#9650;ZipCode</th>  
</tr>
```

Here are some triangles and their decimal values:

► #9658;

▲ #9650;

▼ #9660;

◄ #9668;

Comment: thaks, but i do it with this: .st-sort-ascent:before {
 content: "\25B4";
}

.st-sort-descent:before {
 content: "\25BE";
}